# Faltou traduzir o botão no popup de resposta à própria pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestão de tradução (tradução livre):

> Sim, eu quero escrever uma resposta

ou (tradução mais literal):

> Sim, eu quero publicar uma resposta
>
> Sim, eu quero enviar uma resposta

ou (anglicismo):

> Sim, eu quero postar uma resposta

Comment: Bem que os trechos em negrito podiam ser links para as ações correspondentes. Muita gente deve entender errado, achando que é pra fazer essas coisas na resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto haha agora que você falou, a primeira linha pelo menos parece até um **estímulo** a se comentar uma resposta com outra resposta, e não o contrário! Talvez se dissesse: "...deixe um comentário em vez disso". Mas sua sugestão de transformar em link é ainda melhor.

Comment: É, o primeiro caso é mais grave, já que não faz sentido "editar a pergunta" ao postar uma resposta. Só que se houver várias respostas, o sistema não teria como saber em qual delas criar um novo comentário.

Comment: Continua por traduzir @bfavaretto

Comment: @JorgeB. Alterar isso depende do Gabe, e talvez dos devs do site.